# Prisma Client Initialization Error: Invalid prisma.project.findUniqueOrThrow() invocation

Tags: typescript, express, prisma

I have a schema that looks like so:

```
model Project {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())  
  created DateTime
  organizationID Int
  contentTitle String?
  contentID String?
  clientKey String @unique
  hasData Boolean
  clientViewKey String? @unique
}
```

Calling findUniqueOrThrow is returning the error mentioned in the title.

```
const getProjectOverview = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const qs = require('qs');
    const clientViewKey:string = (<any>req.query).clientViewKey;
    console.log(clientViewKey);
    if (!clientViewKey){
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    try{
        console.log('about to find project');
        const project = await prisma.project.findUniqueOrThrow({
            where: {
                clientViewKey: (<any>req.query)['clientViewKey'],
            }
        });
    return res.sendStatus(200);
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
};
```

In addition to the error, prisma also mentions its unable to reach the DB. I have other files also interacting with prisma DB that function fine. Im unsure whats the issue with this ...

Comment: Prisma Client throws a PrismaClientInitializationError exception if something goes wrong when the query engine is started and the connection to the database is created. 
Errors that can occur include:

1. The provided credentials for the database are invalid
2. There is no database server running under the provided hostname and port
3. The port that the query engine HTTP server wants to bind to is already taken
4. A missing or inaccessible environment variable
5. The query engine binary for the current platform could not be found (generator block)

Comment: Im wondering if it has something to do with how I created a prismsMock in my testfile

Comment: Is your code open source? If yes, can you share the repository so that I can investigate the issue?